# sql modify query with specific value to return as if executed for various specific values

Tags: mysql

There are two tables:

Firstly, `req_data`, which contains a column named `req_id`.

Secondly, `tc_data` which contains a column named `Out-Link`. That column holds (possibly) multiple values of a possible `req_data.req_id` value.

I got the following query

```
SELECT * FROM tc_data WHERE `Out-Link` LIKE '%//specific req_data.req_id value//%'
```

which returns for a specific value the results I want.I just don't know how to modify this query in order to get a result set which would look as if I would have executed the above query for every `req_data.req_id` value in the `req_data.req_id` column.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tc_data INNER JOIN req_data ON tc_data.`Out-Link` LIKE CONCAT('%',req_data.req_id,'%')
```

with no luck (takes very long to execute and does not give desired result).

**Edit 1**

Sample data `req_data`:

```
     req_id         |  *some other columns...*
-------------------------------------------------
abc_ersed_1023      |  ...
-------------------------------------------------
dkd_asdf-2132       |  ...
-------------------------------------------------
mcd-sad_sdf_120323  |  ...
```

sample data `tc_data`

```
    Out-Link         |   some other columns ...
---------------------|--------------------------
dkd_asdf-2132        |...
mcd-sad_sdf_120323   |
------------------------------------------------
mcd-sad_sdf_120323   |...
------------------------------------------------
                     |...
---------------------|--------------------------
abc_ersed_1023       |...
------------------------------------------------
```

Note that `req_id's` can occur in multiple rows in `tc_data`.

Comment: It will be slow because that `LIKE` test can't be indexed, so it has to test every combination. But the syntax looks correct. Can you show some sample data and the desired results?

Comment: Is `Out-Link` a comma-separated list, and you want to match the values in the list? Then you should use `FIND_IN_SET`, not `LIKE`.

Comment: `Out-link` is separated by `\r\n`

Comment: You can use any delimiter with `FIND_IN_SET`. But it's better to normalize your tables.

Comment: as mentioned in comment below changing the design would be a huge effort and does not fit into my time schedule

Comment: OK, then use `FIND_IN_SET`, as explained in the question I marked this as a duplicate of.

Comment: I made a mistake closing this question. `FIND_IN_SET` can only be used with comma-separated lists, it doesn't allow you to specify a custom delimiter.

Comment: I tried FIND_IN_SET(req_data.req_id,replace(tc_data.`Out-Link`,'\r\n',',')), but still not the desired result

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Are you sure it contains `\r\n` and not just `\n`?

Comment: doing SELECT * FROM tc_data WHERE FIND_IN_SET('specific value',replace(tc_data.`Out-Link`,'\r\n',',')) works, however doing SELECT * FROM tc_data INNER JOIN req_data ON FIND_IN_SET(req_data.req_id,replace(tc_data.`Out-Link`,'\r\n',',')) is apparently never ending... `tc_data`contains about 14000 rows, `req_data`contains about 4000 rows

Comment: This type of query can't be indexed. It's going to be very slow. Sorry.

Comment: never ending as in 188 seconds

Comment: It has to do that `REPLACE` every time it compares two rows, and `FIND_IN_SET` is also slow. When you have a poorly designed database, you don't get good results.

Comment: can you tell me why it is returning more rows than any of the tables have? I understand the query like that: Take `req_data's` `req_id`, take `tc_data's` `Out-Link` and return the row of the corresponding `req_data.req_id` if this `req_id`is found in the corresponding `tc_data.Out-Link` row. Is my understanding correct? If yes, shouldn't be the maximum of returned rows be maxof(`req_data`)?

Comment: It's returning a result row for each pair that matches. If one `Out-Link` matches multiple `req_id`, it will return a result for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the desired result because your `LIKE` clause can mix IDs, for instance, `LIKE '%1%'` will also find IDs `10`, `11`, etc. As said by @Barmar, you should first split your field according to a separator, then use `FIND_IN_SET`, but the performances would remain as bad, because no index could be used.

About the poor performances:

- first, the design of your tables is very bad. It seems that you have a many-to-many relation between the entities in `req_data` and in `tc_data`. In such cases, you need a table to do the link, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE req_to_tc_data ( 
    req_id ..., 
    tc_id ...);
```

- <strike>In case it is not possible to change the design of your tables: the problem is that a query using a `LIKE` clause as yours can't use indexes. Assuming you use a MySQL database, if you wanted to be able to use an index, the `Out-Link` field should use a `FULLTEXT` index, and the query should use a `MATCH...AGAINST...` clause, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.htm</strike>

  edit: oh, I just read in the documentation: "The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.". So the `FULLTEXT` index solution won't work. You have to fix the design of your database.

Comment: the database design is not mine, so it would be quiet some work to refactor it hence I would rather make it work if possible

Comment: I forgot to mention it but no id value in `req_data.req_id` is a prefix of another one

Comment: OK, so your query should return the desired result, unless you need to add a `DISTINCT` clause to filter duplicates? Also, you should try the `FIND_IN_SET` solution, but I suspect it won't improve the performances. A solution is to keep the tables the same, but to add the link table I mentioned, and to populate it based on the `Out-link` field. This could be done in a temporary table at server startup if you don't want to permanently modify the database.